# How to print a pyramidal pattern

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, printf, nested-loops

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,j,k,m;
    printf("Enter the number of lines ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n-i;j++)
            printf(" ");

        for(k=1;k<=2*i-1;k++)
            printf("%d",2*i-1);

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This should be the expected result

```
       1
    1  2  1
 1  2  3  2  1
```

But i am getting this output:

```
  1
 333
55555
```

Comment: For your next question please learn how to format questions correctly. It's easy and it will take hardly 5 minutes to grab the basics. Have you done some basic debugging?  Have you used a pencil and a piece of paper? Also the `design-patterns` tag is not at all related to your question.

Comment: Your loop that is printing the number changes `k` but prints `2*i-1`. You probably want `k` in there if you want the number printed to change each iteration. And where are you printing a space _after_ a number?

Comment: This problem is called **Pascal's triangle**. Check this for [more](https://www.scaler.com/topics/pascal-triangle-program-in-c/).

Comment: Set your compiler's warning level higher -- your program has an unused variable (m).

Answer (score 2):

In this inner for loop

```
for(k=1;k<=2*i-1;k++)
    printf("%d",2*i-1);
```

there is outputted the same value `2*i - 1`. So what you do is what you get.

Pay attention to that you need in the same line to output at first numbers in the increasing order starting from 1 and then in the decreasing order ending with also 1.

Also there is no spaces between outputted values.

The code can be written in different ways using various kinds of loops.

I can suggest the following solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    const unsigned int MAX_HEIGHT = 50;

    while (1)
    {
        unsigned int n;

        printf( "Enter the height of a triangle not greater than %u (0 - exit): ", MAX_HEIGHT );

        if (scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0) break;

        int width = 1 + snprintf( NULL, 0, "%d", n );

        putchar( '\n' );

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i++ < n; )
        {

            unsigned int  j = 1;

            printf( "%*u", ( n - i + 1 ) * width, j );

            while ( j != i)
            {
                printf( "%*u", width, ++j );
            }

            while (j != 1)
            {
                printf( "%*u", width, --j );
            }

            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output can look like for example

```
Enter the height of a triangle not greater than 50 (0 - exit): 15

                                            1
                                         1  2  1
                                      1  2  3  2  1
                                   1  2  3  4  3  2  1
                                1  2  3  4  5  4  3  2  1
                             1  2  3  4  5  6  5  4  3  2  1
                          1  2  3  4  5  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
                       1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
                    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
                 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
              1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
           1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
        1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1

Enter the height of a triangle not greater than 50 (0 - exit): 10

                             1
                          1  2  1
                       1  2  3  2  1
                    1  2  3  4  3  2  1
                 1  2  3  4  5  4  3  2  1
              1  2  3  4  5  6  5  4  3  2  1
           1  2  3  4  5  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
        1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1

Enter the height of a triangle not greater than 50 (0 - exit): 5

         1
       1 2 1
     1 2 3 2 1
   1 2 3 4 3 2 1
 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1

Enter the height of a triangle not greater than 50 (0 - exit): 3

     1
   1 2 1
 1 2 3 2 1

Enter the height of a triangle not greater than 50 (0 - exit): 1

 1

Enter the height of a triangle not greater than 50 (0 - exit): 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            printf("%d",2*i-1);
```

1. You don't allow a space between numbers, so you get all of them together.
2. You print `i` variable, which is the row number, you should print something related to `j`, instead.  But think that you must do in two loops, one growing from 1 to the line number, and a second, descending from the line number minus one, to 1.

Also it is important that you give meaningful names to your variables, so you understand your code.  If you don't you make the mistakes you are making above.

instead of

```
       for(k=1;k<=2*i-1;k++)
            printf("%d",2*i-1);
```

use

```
       for (int left = 1; left <= i; left++)
           printf(" %d", left);
       for (int right = row - 1; right >= 1) /* for row, see below, the complete example */
           printf(" %d", right);
```

and you will get separate numbers growing and descending.

In order to make the full set of numbers perfectly aligned, I'd print the biggest number (the biggest number you are going to print is the number of rows, as your piramid has this number in the middle of the base in the last line)  This will make (one plus) the lenght of the field to use to print the number.  So, first:

```
int field_size;
{
   char buffer[10];
   snprintf(" %d", n);
   field_size = strlen(buffer);
} /* as buffer is not needed anymore, this can be condensed in just one statement, see below. */
```

then the three loops:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
    /* print an empty string using field_size places */
    for (int first = 1; first < n; first++)
        printf("%*s", field_size, "");

    /* print left side of the pyramid */
    for (int left = 1; left <= row; left++)
        printf("%*d", field_size, left);

    /* and then the right side */
    for (int right = row; right >= 1; right--)
        printf("%*d", field_size, right);

    puts(""); /* this will print the final line end */
}
```

finally, your program should be something (more optimizations have also been done here) as (complete example):

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n = 10; /* n is the number of rows to print */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:")) != EOF) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'n': n = atoi(optarg); break;
        }
    }

    /* determine the field size to build a proper piramid */
    int field_size = snprintf(NULL, 0, " %d", n);

    /* print piramid by rows, from the peak to the base */
    for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {

        /* print spaces before left part, number of spaces is
         * (n - row) times the field size, so we print it directly
         * using a variable size field to print the empty string. */
        printf("%*s", (n - row) * field_size, "");

        /* left part, numbers increasing */
        for (int left = 1; left <= row; left++)
            printf("%*d", field_size, left);

        /* right part, numbers decreasing */
        for (int right = row-1; right > 0; right--)
            printf("%*d", field_size, right);

        /* final end of line */
        puts("");
    }
}
```

(you can use `-n` option with a number argument to indicate the number of rows you want printed, by default 10) E.g.:

```
$ a.out -n 2
   1
 1 2 1
$ a.out -n 20
                                                           1
                                                        1  2  1
                                                     1  2  3  2  1
                                                  1  2  3  4  3  2  1
                                               1  2  3  4  5  4  3  2  1
                                            1  2  3  4  5  6  5  4  3  2  1
                                         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
                                      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
                                   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
                                1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
                             1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
                          1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
                       1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
                    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
                 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
              1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
           1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
        1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
$ _
```